# Serving Different Size Images For Different Devices Based On Resolution Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, responsive-design

**EXAMPLE:** [This website](http://mashable.com/) is a very good example.

**STEP-1:** In one tab

- just load [the page](http://mashable.com/)
- **View** any image in the far right column. You'll see that they are 638x368 in resolution

**STEP-2:** Open a new tab, and...

- load [the page](http://mashable.com/) and open Firebug or Developer Tools (<kbd>F12</kbd>)
- go to the **Network** (or **Net**) tab
- resize the browser and reload the page
- Maximize the browser window again
- **View** any image in the far right column. You'll see that they are 356x205 in resolution

Clearly this is some JavaScript/jQuery trickery (+ some other tech), because if you inspect any of the images in the far right column, you'll see code like this:

```
<div class="article-img-container">
  <a data-turbo-target="post-slider" href="http://mashable.com/2012/12/27/gdigital-therapy-dog/">
    <span class="_ppf">
      <span data-q="true" data-s="http://rack.2.mshcdn.com/media/.../438c2f93/107/GeriJoy.jpg" data-z="638x368#"></span>
      <span data-q="(min-resolution: 1.5dppx)" data-s="http://rack.3.mshcdn.com/media/.../46c08de9/107/GeriJoy.jpg" data-z="1276x736#"></span>
      <span data-q="(max-width: 1160px)" data-s="http://rack.2.mshcdn.com/media/.../fa9bdb7b/107/GeriJoy.jpg" data-z="356x205#"></span>
      <span data-q="(max-width: 1160px) and (min-resolution: 1.5dppx)" data-s="http://rack.3.mshcdn.com/media/.../42ebf99d/107/GeriJoy.jpg" data-z="712x410#"></span>
      <span data-q="(max-width: 480px)" data-s="http://rack.2.mshcdn.com/media/.../948312d1/107/GeriJoy.jpg" data-z="280x157#"></span>
      <span data-q="(max-width: 480px) and (min-resolution: 1.5dppx)" data-s="http://rack.0.mshcdn.com/media/.../da1d8905/107/GeriJoy.jpg" data-z="560x314#"></span>
      <img src="http://rack.2.mshcdn.com/media/ZgkyMDEyLzEyLzI3L2QyL0dlcmlKb3kuNWYyZWYuanBnCnAJdGh1bWIJNjM4eDM2OCMKZQlqcGc/438c2f93/107/GeriJoy.jpg">
    </span>
  </a>
</div>
```

...which doesn't exist if you `view-source` of the page. Is there an open source javascript library that does something like this?

And what do we call this? **Adaptive Images**?

The plain and simple question that I want to ask is... is it possible to serve different size images to different devices based on the view-port size of their browser or their screen resolution?

Comment: Just found an awesome article: **[Which responsive images solution should you use?](http://css-tricks.com/which-responsive-images-solution-should-you-use/)**

Answer (score 1):

The great answer is this has been possible without javascript for a little while now

In the future the `<picture>` element is exactly what will be used and needed. The HTML for it looks like the following

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="examples/images/large.jpg" media="(min-width: 1000px)">
    <source srcset="examples/images/medium.jpg" media="(min-width: 800px)">
    <source srcset="examples/images/small.jpg">

    <img srcset="examples/images/small.jpg" alt="Desciption of image">
</picture>
```

This is essentially the same technique as the one below, but the form of writing it is made easier and it is serves to an `img` as opposed to a `background-image`. As of writing this answer, we can use [a polyfill](http://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/) to use this format or a `@media` query

CSS2 Media Types introduced `@media` queries which allow us to affect different styles of a page based on the viewport dimensions among many other things. This allows us to [serve larger images](http://benfrain.com/how-to-serve-high-resolution-website-images-for-retina-displays-new-ipadiphone4/) as background images only if they're needed. An example of its use is the following

```
.myImg { background-image:url(myurlSmall.png); } /* Start with smallest */

/* Serve larger image only if needed */
@media (min-width:400px) {
    .myImg { background-image:url(myurlMedium.png); }
}
@media (min-width:1200px) {
    .myImg { background-image:url(myurlLarge.png); }
}
/* etc. */
```