# Detecting 4K/Ultra High Definition (UHD) with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

4K devices are becoming more popular. I am developing a website and I have a mobile phone that has a UHD display. I noticed that the images are blurry. I immediately thought could it be that fact it was 4K. By doubling the image size as shown in the examples below I found that it was not blurry anymore.

**4K/UHD:**`<img src="/images/logo-192x128.png" width="96" height="64" />`

**Standard HD/SD:**`<img src="/images/logo-96x64.png" width="96" height="64" />`

My question is, how can you detect a 4K/UHD display using JavaScript so that you can dynamically include the double-resolution images when a 4K display is detected. The reason I want to do this is to cut down on my pages' load times as loading these larger resolution images is resource intensive.

Comment: Perhaps media query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933143/css-media-queries-pixel-density-desktop-and-mobile-devices

Comment: There's a media query for pixel ratio

Comment: For logos and icons (but not for pictures), you can sidestep the issue with vector fonts (like glyphicons) instead of bitmap images.

Comment: @Cory Danielson Do you have any clue what the pixel ratio is for UHD/4K?

Comment: Nope, you can test it out with `window.devicePixelRatio` I'm pretty it'll be the same value that you'll see in CSS. On my normal monitor window.devicePixelRatio is 1, but on a retina display it's 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write your own function to test

```
test4k = function() {
var width, height, test;

width = screen.height
height = screen.width

if( height < width) {
    test = height
} else {
    test = width
}

console.log(test)

return ( test > 4000 ) 
}
```

Or you could do inline.

```
test4k = function() { return ((screen.height < screen.width) ? (screen.width > 3839 ) : (screen.height > 3839 ) ); }
```

I used 3839 for this check because of some displays stated here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4K_resolution.

I don't know if there is a working method for this though...

To the reason why you are doing this test, have you tested this: [Serving Different Size Images For Different Devices Based On Resolution Using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14052872/serving-different-size-images-for-different-devices-based-on-resolution-using-ja)

Also have you asked yourself this questions: http://css-tricks.com/which-responsive-images-solution-should-you-use/ ?

Comment: I'm not sure if that will work, because there can be lower resolutions that the 3840 such as on a mobile phone, but on a 4K display it will still display twice that amount of pixels per square inch, am I correct?  The question is very difficult to answer at this time but based on responses I'm trying to get a feel for the right answer here there has been many interesting responses

Comment: I don't own a 4k phone, could you upload or link a image  so I could understand? Have you tried using the media in the image to choose based on width?